# GNU make not expanding Environmental Variable

Tags: makefile, gnu

I am trying to use a makefile but my GNU `make` does not seem to be expanding environment variables correctly.
Using Ubuntu 22 and GNU Make v4.3, I am in a Terminal and I have a script which sets up some environment variables:

```
TOOLCHAIN_PATH="/opt/armc7-eabihf-glibc/bin"
TOOL_CC="arm_linux-gcc"
```

These both seem to be set up correctly as I can type "`echo STOOLCHAIN_PATH`" and it prints out the correct text string "`/opt/armc7-eabihf-glibc/bin`"

But now in the Makefile there is a line:

```
CC=$(TOOLCHAIN_PATH)/$(TOOL_CC)
```

and when I run make this is expanded as just `/`

I can confirm the environment variables are not expanding with the line:

```
 $(info TCP is $(TOOLCHAIN_PATH))
```

which simply gives me "TCP is"

Do I have to do something special to allow `make` to access the environmental variables that I can clearly see in the terminal before I run `make` ?

---

I tried running the `settings.sh` script which sets up the environmental variables correctly.

I tried running `make`, and the command line it generated did not have the necessary compiler name in it.

I added the line `$(info TCP is $(TOOLCHAIN_PATH))`, which confirmed that the variable was expanding to nothing.

Comment: In a shell script, BLAH=foo is **NOT an environment variable**. It is a _shell_ variable. Expanding $BLAH _in the same shell_ works, but expanding it in another program like make doesn't. To make it an _environment_ variable, in a Bourne-family shell use `export BLAH` (in _some_ shells you can combine with the assignment as `export BLAH=foo`), or depending on shell `declare -x` or `typeset -x`, or have shell option flag `a` set before creating it; in C shell family use `setenv` instead of `set`. Other/odder shells are different and you didn't identify yours.

Comment: As a help, you can run the program `env` to see the environment variables (there are lots of ways of course but this is an easy one).  So if you run `env | grep TOOLCHAIN_PATH` and it shows the right value, then you have successfully created an environment variable in your shell and `make` will see it.  If it doesn't show anything then `make` will not see it either.

Comment: dave_thompson_085 : your comment about "a shell script is not an environmental variable" I've checked the original script and it does contain the necessary 'export' lines and I think that makes the shell variables into environmental variables. They're definitely there because I type 'echo $BLAH' and see 'foo' printed out. I simply can't work out why the Make command isn't picking them up.

Comment: MadScientist : thanks for the comment, I didn't use env, I used echo instead. If I type 'echo $TOOLCHAIN_PATH' then the reply is the pathname string that was entered by the first script.